# How do i make QtCreator to stop using both gtk+2.x and gtk3

Tags: 14.04, gtk, qt-creator, opencv

I am trying to build an opencv project in QtCreator on an ARM board ( ODROID-XU4).
Its a gui application but when i try to execute the code it throws an error

> "GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK3 in the same
>   process is not supported"

I am doing SURF detection using QtWidgets application in QtCreator 3.0.1. 
I have a window with 2 buttons and 2 smaller label windows to show the camera feed. But i am also using some OpenCV outputs which displays output windows.

I have Raspberry Pi 2 which runs the same code without any issue.

Is there any way i can stop Qtcreator from using both the gtk's? Or can i uninstall ? If yes how?

OS - Ubuntu 14.04
Device - ODROID-XU4

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information about your project. This isn't QtCreator doing it, but your project is trying to link to at least two libraries, at least one of which is linked to Gtk+ 2.x, and at least one of which is linked to Gtk+ 3.x. If your application is Gtk+ 3.x, you will have to avoid linking to libraries that link to Gtk+ 2.x.

Comment: Please see the edited question. Is there anyway i can figure out which gui is using which gtk version in the code?

Comment: @dobey thank you for your response. I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dobey i followed his suggestion to compile opencv using cmake.

So here's how i got it working.
Earlier i compiled just WITH_GTK=ON but it didn't work.
I had to compile opencv using cmake with flags WITH_GTK=ON & WITH_GTK_2_X=ON.